# How to pass debug flags to node with node-tap?

Tags: node.js, tap

I'm trying to add a new test to a node module that uses `node-tap` (the module is `dnode`). What's the best way to pass the flag `--expose-gc` to the test script? I guess I'll have to write some wrapper, but what's the best way to do that?

Example tap test script from that project: https://github.com/substack/dnode/blob/master/test/simple.js

Comment: Meh, I'll add that functionality now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Talked about it with isaacs and wrote a pull request he'll probably merge soon: https://github.com/isaacs/tap-runner/pull/6.
Now my question can be answered as follows:*

Use a shebang:

```
#! node --expose-gc
```